# os.stat() returning wrong permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone explain this curious behavior to me?

Windows 10; Python 3.7.3; Cygwin GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)

I start a `bash` shell and run this...

```
$ echo "test" > test.txt; chmod 444 test.txt
mode of 'test.txt' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0444 (r--r--r--)
```

... and that creates a nice read-only file. Then I run...

```
python.exe testwrite.py
```

... which is this...

```
import os
import pathlib
import stat

print('--- Write permission test ---')
test_file = pathlib.Path('./test.txt').resolve()
f_mode = os.stat(test_file).st_mode
print(f' User: {bool(f_mode & stat.S_IWUSR)}')
print(f'Group: {bool(f_mode & stat.S_IWGRP)}')
print(f'Other: {bool(f_mode & stat.S_IWOTH)}')
try:
    with open(test_file, 'w') as fo:
        fo.write('sdf')
        print('File written!')
except PermissionError:
    print('File write error! Deleting it.')
    os.remove(test_file)
    print('File deleted.')
    with open(test_file, 'w') as fo:
        fo.write('sdf')
        print('File written!')
```

... and that creates this output...

```
--- Write permission test ---
 User: True
Group: True
Other: True
File write error! Deleting it.
File deleted.
File written!
```

Why does `os.stat()` tell me I have full write permissions?
Also, how does `open()` fail but `os.remove()` succeeds?

I understand that Windows does "interesting" things with file permissions, but this would seem to suggest that certain Python import disagree with themselves.

I'm writing a utility that walks through directories, reporting files for which the user doesn't have full control over. Is there something better that `os.stat()` I should be using? My research to this point does not suggest there is, but this behavior is curious.

**Update:**

As a workaround, I can do...

```
try:
    open(test_file,'a') as fo:
        pass
except PermissionError:
    print('File is not writable!')
```

...so I can actually open the file without changing it, and still get a more concrete permissions test. It works, but it feels... dirty. :)

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod): *"Although Windows supports `chmod()`, you can only set the file’s read-only flag with it (via the `stat.S_IWRITE` and `stat.S_IREAD` constants or a corresponding integer value). All other bits are ignored.*" Presumably because Windows does not have Unix-style read/write/execute permissions. Permissions set in bash are presumably not at the OS level, although bash might emulate them for itself.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So, if I remove BASH from the equation and set permissions with Explorer (Right click, Properties, Security, Edit, pick my group, and deny everything except full control), my code should act differently. Yet, I get the same results...?

Comment: Although, if I set the Read-only flag with Right-click , Priorities (just like you mentioned) I do indeed get the expected result from os.stat(). So then, does Python have a way to get Windows-flavored permissions to let me know if writing a file will bomb?